# SpTBX: not bold font, for panel title

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

- on left- my app (Aluminum theme)
- on right- Cubic Explorer also using SpTBX (theme is same)

How to make `TSpTbxDockablePanel` title non-bold, like on right side? I see panel uses ParentFont so font is set as non-bold.

[image: panel title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caption of a dockable panel is actually a *label* item, the panel's own font has no effect. You can access the label item's - a *right align spacer* - font settings like the below:

```
MySpTBXDockablePanel.Options.RightAlignSpacer.FontSettings.Style := [];
```

You can put this f.i. in the OnCreate event of your form.